# Build mysql-connector-c++-8.0.17-src with MinGW on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mysql-connector, mingw-w64

After successfully going through the CMake (CMake-3.12.3) configure step with:

```
cmake.exe ..\mysql-connector-c++-8.0.17-src -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DBUILD_STATIC=ON
```

I got stuck at:

```
cmake.exe --build . --config Debug
```

which gives me:

```
[  2%] Built target save_linker_opts
[  3%] Building CXX object uuid/src/CMakeFiles/uuid_gen.dir/uuid_gen.cc.obj
D:\Daten\LiDoSourcen\mysql-connector-c++-8.0.17-src\cdk\extra\uuid\src\uuid_gen.cc:46:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef CRITICAL_SECTION pthread_mutex_t'
   46 | typedef CRITICAL_SECTION pthread_mutex_t;
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/string:55,
                 from D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/stdexcept:39,
                 from D:\Daten\LiDoSourcen\mysql-connector-c++-8.0.17-src\cdk\extra\uuid\src\uuid_gen.cc:40:
D:/Daten/Portable/MinGw-msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/pthread.h:271:18: note: previous declaration as 'typedef intptr_t pthread_mutex_t'
  271 | typedef intptr_t pthread_mutex_t;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

as a result.

I updated the MinGW / msys2 environmet yesterday, so I should have the most recent version of the compiler.

I looked at both locations, but could not spot any obvious `#define` or something I could use to get a proper compilation.

Any hints - or questions?

Comment: Have you tried using Cygwin instead of MinGW? Your issue is similar to [this](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc/issues/40).

Comment: No, but looking at the other answer, it Iooks like have to seek the answer by modifying the compile environment.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I got the same problem.@GerhardBuch

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build `untrunc` on windows using `mingw-w64`.
When installing mingw-w64, it asks for your preferred threading model, which you can change.

The Windows build succeeded. After installing all packages in `cygwin`, I then installed `NASM` and `YASM` and added its path to the environment variable `PATH`.

Then I built `libav-12.3` using MinGW using:

```
./configure --enable-pthreads --enable-shared
```

and then ran the `make` command using cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - the threading model seems to be good target to investigate on ...

Comment: You are welcome. Let us know you solved the issue and the approach